# c# - Only one UdpClient of two on same port and machine sends datagram

Tags: c#, udp, broadcast, datagram, udpclient

I have two applications using `UdpClient` with same settings (including port) on the same machine running at same time. Call them A and B, where `UdpClient` of A is started first. When I send datagram from A to B (127.0.0.1), B does not receive it. When I send datagram from B to A (127.0.0.1), it is received. When I send it to broadcast address, it works in both ways.

Code (Commandline application):

```
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
            client.Client.SetSocketOption(
            SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            client.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 7894));
            client.EnableBroadcast = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press key to send datagram");

            while (true)
            {
                if (client.Available > 0)
                {
                    IPEndPoint ep = null;
                    client.Receive(ref ep);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received");
                }
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    client.Send(new byte[] { 1 }, 1, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7894));
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent");
                }
            }
```

Datagrams from instance which was started first are not transfered.

Comment: The problem is probably in receiving.

Comment: In short: that's expected behavior.